# #1060 - Duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, create-table

Why does this query errors `(1060) Duplicate column name 'studentID'` in MySQL? How can I prevent it?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable 
    select * from member_infos 
    join contact_infos on member_infos.studentID=contact_infos.studentID
```

Comment: without using select * specify column names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use MySQL's `USING` clause (alternative to `ON`), it will only product one copy of the shared field used to join those tables in the results of the `SELECT`.

If there are other fields sharing names, `USING` cannot help you; you will need to list out all fields explicitly in order to exclude (or alias) fields with the same name.

`USING` is covered in the [MySQL JOIN documention](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN result contains 2 columns with the same name `studentID`. From that result you want to create a table. But a table needs unique column names.

So best is not using `select * from ...` but name every column.